# How often is an element drawn, that is drawn at least once?

Tags: combinatorics, statistics

Consider $m$ elements and $k$ draws with replacement. Then, each element is drawn on average $k/m$ times. But how often is an element drawn that is at least drawn once?

Initially, I thought this should be $1+\frac{k-1}{m}$. The reason is that I draw it at least once and then in the k-1 remaining draws, I draw $\frac{k-1}{m}$ on average.

But this does not make sense if you consider the $k\gg m$ limit. Because then this would be $1+k/m$ although it should be k/m. I also performed simulations showing that $1+\frac{k-1}{m}$ is wrong. Therefore I would be grateful for any help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's go back to first principles.  Letting $X$ be the number of times the first object is pulled, we can say that

$$E[X]=0\cdot \Pr(X=0)+1\cdot \Pr(X=1)+2\cdot \Pr(X=2)+\dots$$

Now, we ask what is $E[X\mid X>0]$

$$E[X\mid X>0]=1\cdot \Pr(X=1\mid X>0)+2\cdot \Pr(X=2\mid X>0)+\dots$$

Let us look at a specific one of these in more detail... $\Pr(X=i\mid X>0)$.  Well, by definition of conditional probability, this is $\dfrac{\Pr(X=i\cap X>0)}{\Pr(X>0)}$ and noting that for positive $k$ the numerator simplifies to just $\Pr(X=i)$ we see that the expressions for $E[X]$ and for $E[X\mid X>0]$ are identical with the exception of that every probability is being divided by $\Pr(X>0)$.

You know already that $E[X]=\dfrac{k}{m}$.  It follows that $E[X\mid X>0] = \dfrac{~~\frac{k}{m}~~}{\Pr(X>0)}$.  Taking the time to find $\Pr(X>0)=1-\left(1-\frac{1}{m}\right)^k$ and substituting that in gives the final answer:

$$E[X\mid X>0] = \frac{k}{m(1-(1-\frac{1}{m})^k)}$$

Comment: Thank you! Your result matches the numerical result for k>=1. 

However, the number of draws is Poisson distributed with mean k. Hence for k<1, your equation does not fit my simulation. 

Do you know how the result could be extended for k<=1? Since this is not my original question, I will otherwise also accept your answer.

Comment: Maybe have a look at my follow up question: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4698536/how-often-is-an-element-drawn-that-is-drawn-at-least-once-advanced