# How often is an element drawn, that is drawn at least once? (advanced)

Tags: combinatorics, statistics

I recently posted the following question:

Consider  elements and  draws with replacement. Then, each element is drawn on average / times. But how often is an element drawn that is at least drawn once?

The question was solved by @JMoravitz [How often is an element drawn, that is drawn at least once?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4698415/how-often-is-an-element-drawn-that-is-drawn-at-least-once).

Now the question that I want actually to answer is slightly different:

Consider $m$ elements and $k$ draws with replacement. **The number of draws $k$ is Poisson distributed with mean $\lambda$**. Then, each element is drawn on average / times. But how often is an element drawn that is at least drawn once? Running a simulation, I noticed that the answer given in the link above slightly underestimates the true value. Furthermore, the answer given gets smaller than 1 for $\lambda<1$, which is clearly wrong. Is there any hope to also take this into account and to get a closed-form expression?

[image]